# jQuery Auto complete dropdown box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, drop-down-menu

After almost two days of searching and R&D finally I've derived some of the following jQuery based auto-complete plugins which I find worth and suitable for my web-app.

I've an MVC2 based web-app that I'm developing in ASP.Net C#. I've L2S (LINQ to SQL) as my DAL and I use service layer architecture to fetch data via the L2S.

> Now, I'm going to have some "Look ups"
> in which the list of selection might
> be big (i.e. 1000 or more records) so
> at times I want my auto-complete look
> up to be dynamic (i.e. I give the page
> from which it'll get the values and
> show in the dropdown) But there're
> simple ones also like 10-20 values
> which I want to render statically.

In short I need something v.simple and straight forward auto-complete plugin which does the job without asking me too many questions or requiring too many .js files (of course excluding jQuery).

Here's the summary of my R&D along with my conclusion -

> 1. - Simpler, static, has contains search(
>      **[http://frontensemble.com/hyjack/](https://frontensemble.com/hyjack/)**)
> 2. - - Simple, static/dynamic, only starts with search(
>        **[http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/](https://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)**)
> 3. - Complex, static/dynamic, combobox like contains search and much more (
>      **[http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
>      http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete/](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)**
>      )
> 4. - - - Simpler, static/dynamic, has contains search  (
>          **[http://www.dyve.net/jquery?autocomplete](https://web.archive.org/web/20091019155637/http://dyve.net:80/jquery/?autocomplete)**
>          )

*Pls consider the *(dot) above as my ratings. After some insights and demo reviews I've concluded that I'll go with #4 the dyve.net auto-complete plugin because it seems to be doing everything I need and most importantly its not complex.*

You'll find that #3 is rich in functionality and has much more but its big and gets complex so I've to opt it. FYI, #2 is nothing more but the primary version of #3 (but the only problem I faced is that it (#2) only has starts-with match, contains match is much better)

Hope I'm on track.

---

EDIT:

> Well after a night-out and more then
> 20 hours of struggling and
> experimenting. I conclude that with
> jQuery I need to choose something
> which has a bigger support. With
> option #4 -The main problem came in
> when I wanted to populate a child dropdown based on parent
> It does populate dynamically but it persists the old items as well so while searching - the old ones will popup!
> I tried its cacheFlush, etc.. but it didn't worked. Finally, I posted my comment on the author's google code page and left it.

- My final take would be to use
  **jQueryui** - well I can do with some
  complexity when I'm getting too many
  other plugins who share the same
  library. So, my vote goes to **option
  #3**

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by the comments on search for each. For example, what does it mean when you say "only starts with search" or "has contains search"?

Comment: @Hemant Tank: A few things **1** You can include just the jQueryUI autocomplete files and not the entire jQueryUI library, **2** the jQueryUI widget satisfies all of your requirements, and **3** the jQueryUI widget is probably best supported by the community here at StackOverflow and is constantly being tweaked/updated/fixed by the jQueryUI team. Can you tell which one I would recommend?

Comment: By search I mean the search performed by the auto-complete as we type into the box. ----

Comment: @Andrew : I saw the jQueryUI and it added some core files which it says are required (you'll find the dependency on the download pg)

Comment: @Hemant: Understood `:)`

Comment: I've only ever used the second one you mention, but the search for that one isn't implemented by the plugin. I've implemented "contains" searches with it by writing my mysql queries that way. The plugin is just displaying the results the php script on the server-side of the ajax request returns.

Comment: My final take would be to use jQueryui - well I can do with some complexity when I'm getting too many other plugins who share the same library. So, my vote goes to option #3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've settled with the fact that it doesn't cache any search results and that it'll perform an AJAX based search upon each term as the user types.

I'll include the jQuery min file instead of including a bunch of diff files which size about the same when bundled. It is better to have a single file download rather then multiple chunks esp when that one file is as small as jquery min.

Other ref which might be preferable in certain situations:

> **hyjack:** Cool because it converts a dropdown into auto-complete. Great if
>   I was able to render the dropdown
>   instead of dynamic lookup.
>   http://frontensemble.com/hyjack/
>
> **jQuery Autocompleter:** I had to let it go because of an issue with
>   Parent-child auto-complete
>   http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/issues/detail?id=41